# Keep data no apps while reinstalling Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu 17.10 from live usb.
I have many problems during reinstallation.

So I need to only keep data not apps, Is there an option for that in Ubuntu reinstallation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to preserve the `/home` folder and all of it's subdirectories (it is unlikely that your data would be stored anywhere else, and no applications installed via apt-get will be there).

Here are some methods which would allow you to do this:

- Backup /home to any kind of backup drive, either as a direct copy or as .tar.gz.
- Repartition your existing hard drive. Create a new partition for /home, and move all your data there. Use that as a /home partition when you reinstall.